# Expression for a double product of exponential functions

Tags: exponential-function, products

I would like to obtain a nice analytic expression for
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^k (1-e^{-x_{ij}}),
$$
where $0<x_{ij}<1$. I saw something similar in the link https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3138951/725141, but I am not sure if it's possible to extend this result. What I mean by "nice" is basically to get rid of the products.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite as a single product,

$$\prod_{l=1}^{nk}(1-e^{-x_l})$$ with the re-indexing $l=i+n(j-1)$.

Note that the solution given in the linked question is just the expansion of the product and is in fact more complicated than the original product.

Comment: Thanks Yves, but I think this does not work for all $x_{ij}$, for example we could have $x_{ij}=t_i s_j+d_i$, how does the new index $l$ will work?

Comment: @Ludwig: $x_{i+n(j-1)}=t_is_j+d_i$. But you didn't ask that.